# How to stop a Swing Timer?

Tags: java, swing, timer

i have a problem in my code, because i cant stop the swing.timer

//some code here

I tried to put a if statement but it doesnt working.

```
Static int gScore = 1000;
t = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        score01.setText("score: " + gScore);
        gScore--;     
    }
});
t.start();
t.setRepeats(true);
if(gScore== 970){//A
    t.stop();
    t.setRepeats(false);    
}//A
```

i want to stop the timer when it reach to a given value and remove it inside the JFrame

Comment: That code won't even compile. You're going to have to say more than just "it doesn't working". Put debugging statements there to see what's happening.

Comment: Please format code, and post full method.

Answer (score 0):

Your timer shall be final

```
t.cancel();
t.purge();
```

and when declaring your timer, set it as final

```
final Timer t = new Timer(...)
```

Comment: what do you mean? i should put t.cancel(); inside the if statement?

Comment: I have tried to indent your code and you have extra curly braces everywhere, please put all your code before we can define where exactly to add it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code as followed:

```
static int gScore = 1000;
final Timer t = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    score01.setText("score: " + gScore);
    gScore--;
    if(gScore== 970){//A
      t.stop();
    }//A
  }
});
t.start();
```

Comment: I did this but it doesnt solve my problem. because i cant put an if statement after the gScore--;
I can only put the if statement after the }); and still, it doesnt work

Comment: Timer variable must be declared as final, or as member-variable of class.

Comment: When using listeners you can get the source object by using the getSource() method of the event. `Timer timer = (Timer)e.getSource();`